# xQuery to JavaScript require with multiple files

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8

When converting an xQuery script tot JavaScript, I have this line where two XQY files are combined into a single module namespace.

How do I do this in JavaScript?

**Original**

```
import module namespace obj = "http://marklogic.com/solutions/obi/object" at 
                     "/ext/obi/lib/object-service-lib.xqy", "/ext/obi/lib/object-lib.xqy";
```

**Not working:**

```
var obj = require("/ext/obi/lib/object-service-lib.xqy", 
                                                "/ext/obi/lib/object-lib.xqy");
```

**Error**

> [javascript] XDMP-TOOMANYARGS: var obj =
>   require("/ext/obi/lib/object-service-lib.xqy", "/ext/obi/lib/obje --
>   Too many args, expected 1 but got 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could perhaps require the two libraries separately, and then merge them into one manually, but I would skip the hassle, and just treat the two separately. I see not much benefit of merging them, neither in XQuery, nor in SJS..

HTH!